# Does a Shomer help for Eating before Lighting?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, time, eating

The Mishna Berurah (672:10) says

> ואפילו ללמוד אסור משהגיע זמנה וכ"ש אכילה וש"ד ואפילו התחיל פוסק
>
> Even to learn is prohibited once the time of lighting Chanuka candles arrives. And all the more so eating or other things. And even if he started he should stop.

I recall that when it comes to other similar Halachos such as eating [a meal] once the time of davening has come, appointing a shomer (someone to remind him later) helps.

I was wondering if the same applies with lighting the Chanuka candles. In other words, if someone appoints a shomer to remind him to light later, is s/he allowed to eat after the time to light has arrived?

Sources, please.

Comment: Every between mincha maariv Hilchos Chanukah review that I ever heard said yes.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51075&st=&pgnum=81&hilite= I do not know who he is quoting it from.

Comment: this should answer your question http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=56&hilite=

Comment: my question is can one use an alarm clock

Comment: @sam [So ask it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!

Comment: @yydl http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65987

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Dovid Feinstein advised me to appoint my wife as a shomer(es) to remind me to light when we got home so we could eat at a motzei shabbos chanuka Chanukah party without going home to light first.

Comment: But I'm sure it's written open in the books somewhere.