Is a shomer needed for each tefila
For one who davens each tefilla at a different time every day, is it halacha l'maysa that one must set a Shomer to remind them to daven, or else once the earliest zman for each tefilla comes, it's assur to eat/drink or do distracting melacha until they daven that tefilla? Does setting one daily mincha alarm for multiple days ahead of time work as a shomer for the next few days mincha to allow you to always be allowed to eat without worrying about it?

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65987/alarm-clock-in-place-of-a-shomer

And see also https://dinonline.org/2020/10/25/eating-meal-before-mincha-or-maariv/

I'm not sure what you are unsure about. You quoted the halacha just fine.
