# Eat before lighting chanukah candles via alarm, accd to "Guidelines"

Tags: halacha, chanuka, eating

Can someone who has "Guidelines" Chanukah edition by Rabbis Jaeger and Barclay please see in that book if they mention if it is permissible to eat before lighting Chanukah candles if one sets an alarm?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50481/does-a-shomer-help-for-eating-before-lighting

Comment: @yydl that quoted Halichos Shlomo which permitted one to use an alarm clock to remind one to daven.  I'm asking specifically about chanukah lighting.

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Alarm clock in place of a shomer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65987/11501)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Stancyz and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Does the answer have to come from that book specifically or would you like as well answers from others to the same question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 47, of *Guidelines Chanuka* (New Revised Edition) by R. Barclay and R. Jaeger (question 101):

> **When would a person be permitted to work, eat or sleep before lighting
>   [chanuka candles]?**
>
> If he appoints another person to remind him to light the menorah, he
>   is permitted to work, eat, or sleep. Similarly, one may set an
>   electronic alarm that gives an appropriate message.

The source listed for this question is as follows (p.93, on ch. 5):

> כן נראה ע״פ מ״ב הנ״ל (סי׳ רלה ס״ק יז) וע׳ אשי ישראל פכ״ז סק״ס וס״ק פ״ז

the reference to the Mishneh Berurah is from the previous question.

(משנה ברורה סימן רלה ס"ק יז
(יז) לאכול - וכן לישן אפילו דעתו רק לישן קמעא [גמרא] וה"ה דאסור אז לעשות כל המלאכות המבוארות לעיל בסימן רל"ב ס"ב שהם דברים המביאים לידי פשיעה וכ"ש כשהגיע זמן ק"ש בודאי אסור להתחיל בהן [לבוש ופמ"ג ברל"ב ודה"ח] וא"ר מצדד להתיר בהם קודם שהגיע זמן ק"ש. מיהו ללמוד לכו"ע שרי בסמוך לה [ואדרבה מצוה הוא וכמו שאמרו בש"ס אדם בא מן השדה בערב נכנס לביהכ"נ אם רגיל לקרות קורא לשנות שונה וקורא ק"ש ומתפלל] אבל משהגיע זמן ק"ש אסור אף ללמוד כשהוא מתפלל בביתו ביחיד ואם אמר לחבירו שאינו לומד שיזכרנו שיתפלל מותר [אחרונים]: )

this is in the context of eating before krias shema in the evening:

Comment: thanks danny.  also, what does he mean by "appropriate message"?

Comment: Well, It seems to be a message that a person should know to light with it - today smartphones and dumbphones - all phones really, come with the option to display a message.  Mi Yodea is not a halachic psak site, so ask a Rabbi if a regular alarm with no message is permitted.

Comment: danny can you please look at the hebrew source reference that he gives for that question and tell me what it is?

Comment: I checked my guidelines, and I see that question 101 is on page 40 and is same exact question as yours but makes no mention of an alarm ,is your version a newer one, mine is from 2001

Comment: @sam can u tell me what the hebrew source is for that question and answer, found in the back of the book

Comment: The one I have doesnt mention alarm ,but the source is Ishei Yisrael.Will check it later

Comment: @sam can you please list the exact reference, siman and seif that it lists in ishei yisrael

Comment: There is a newer edition that came out, hence the differences in pages

Answer (score 1):

This is from Rabbi Yaakov Robinson ,and was reviewed by Rav Shmuel Fuerst (a talmid muvak of Rav Moshe Feinstein).

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Unless that's a question from the requested book?

Comment: I was under the impression that any reliable source would suffice ,bevause thats exactly what the guidelines does uses reliable sources

Comment: it seems that Rav Furst and Rav Guidelines argue on the nature of a valid alarm - one requires a message the latter does not!

Comment: @DannyF can you please tell me the hebrew reference/source that he gives in guidelines for the question and answer you posted?

Comment: @DannyF the guidelines rabbis hold that only by chanukah is the alarm with no message not sufficient.  they agree by eating before davening that it is sufficient, as they don't message the alarm with the message there by davening, but only a stam alarm.

Comment: @DannyF and yes Rav Fuerst and the Guidelines rabbis do in fact argue by chanukah.